# Threading in python, no errors but program doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am working on a program for my raspberry pi. Currently I am just trying to have the program print "Yellow LED on" or "Red LED on". I am brand new to threading, however not to python. I currently have some code written out however I can not figure out why when I run it, nothing happens and the program never terminates. If anyone has any ideas they would be much appreciated.
I have posted the code below.
Thanks in advance.

```
from threading import Thread
import random
import time

def blinking_LED(n,t):
    i = 10
    for x in range (n,i):
        if (x % 2) == 0:
            color = "yellow"
            n += 1
        else:
            color = "red"
            n += 1
    # output result
        if (color == "yellow"):
            print ("Yellow LED on")
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            print ("Red LED on")
            time.sleep(2)
    #exit function, terminate program
    s.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # value to pass into the functions
    v = 1

    # create threads
    t1 = Thread(target=blinking_LED, args=(v,1))

    # Start threads
    t1.start()

    #tell main thread to stay alive until both threads are done
    t1.join()
```

Comment: What happens if you print something before `v = 1`?

Comment: Still nothing, program runs but no output and it never terminates

Comment: How exactly do you run this? Where do you expect the output of `print` to be written?

Comment: What happens if you print something before doing any imports? Did you successfully run a "hello world" program which does nothing except printing something?

Comment: I run in terminal, using "python3 threadingExample.py". So I would expect the output to show up in the command line

Comment: Not specifically a "hello world" program however all my other programs work fine with this method of running.

Comment: Then your task is now to remove line by line from your program until it works to find out what causes it to not work.

Comment: I'd suggest refreshing your python environment as well OP. If you can't even print and no errors are thrown, then the problem likely isn't even in the code

Comment: This code works fine for me (at least until it reaches the undefined `s` in line 22). OP, what is the output when you run `python3 -c 'print("All good")'`?

Answer (score 0):

```
from threading import Thread
import time


def blinking_LED(n):
    for x in range(n):
        if (x % 2) == 0:
            print("Yellow LED on")
        else:
            print("Red LED on")
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = Thread(target=blinking_LED, args=(10,))
    t1.start()

    # Tell main thread to stay alive until both threads are done
    t1.join()
```

You don't have to call s.quit(), whatever it is, when function returns, the thread will terminate.

I'm not sure where your problem is, your code is frankly a bit hard to read. Look at the example above, it prints " LED on" every second, alternating the colors, and terminates after 10 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, first I need to change "s.quit()" to "exit()". Second, I am not sure why but I copied and pasted all the code into a new file and tried to run it and everything worked fine. I am not sure what the issue was but for some reason it runs now. 
I appreciate all the help!

Comment: You don't need `exit()`, either.